# Android Application is not working in China

Tags: android, localization, google-play, cjk

I developed an application for Taiwan which has Google map in it. Now it's on market but when Chinese people try to install it, it gives an error as follow:

> "The Application does not install successfully."

It's working on all other places. Client thinks it is because of Chinese Simplified language. Does any one faced such error?

Comment: I faced that error when I tried installing the same app that was installed with a different signing key. Did you delete earlier installs from the device. Also can you get a look at the output from logcat when installing the app. That might be helpfull ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs in android when two application have same certificates.So, please uninstall the app which has same certificate & then install the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the google map's problem.

Google servers always work not good on china.

I am Chinese in ChengDu, I recommend you choose **Baidu Map** instead of Google Map.